# Mirror axis -> effect is stronger on one side

Tags: mirror

I am working on a model with the Mirror X axis turned on and I just noticed the effects are starting to get faded on the mirrored side of the model. Here's what I mean:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am really confused as to why did it start to happen just now, it was fine untill now and I am quite far ahead with the model. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

P.S. here it is in edit mode:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a picture of your model in edit mode?

Comment: Yes sure, I will include it in the question.

Comment: that shirt is not mirrored? It may be the cause for it actually, that topology on one side is different or it may have different scale/mass/height and mirrored brush may act differently

Comment: Well I didn't use the Mirror modifier, I only turned on the X axis mirror. In edit mode, it does look like it is different, however I don't know why is that. Should I just delete half of my model and use the Mirror modifier?

Comment: Check if the mesh's origin has 0 as X coordinate. If so in edit mode go to Mesh menu > Symmetrize, and choose which verse ( -X to X or X to -X).

Comment: Also check if object scale is even on all three axes, ideally set to 1:1:1.